# How to use a subquery inside an INTERVAL function in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I want to use Interval function in Teradata much like this :

```
SELECT DATE '1998-08-31' + INTERVAL '30' DAY;
```

But I want to make the date range configurable. That is I want it to be read from a table instead of using a hard coded value like '30' in the above example.
How can I achieve this ? The table from where the date range will be read from will be storing the range as an integer. So I guess it should well be converted to VARCHAR also. Please clarify.
Apparently this did not work

```
SELECT DATE '1998-08-31' + INTERVAL CAST((SELECT config.ask_gift_dt_diff 
FROM ddcoe_tbls.gift_lnk_config config
WHERE bzd_cnst_lnk_ctg_cd = 'ASK GIFT DATE RANGE') AS VARCHAR(20)) DAY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not work, `'30'` is not a string, it's a part of an `interval`.

You need to either `CAST` the number to an `INTERVAL DAY` or multiply an `INTERVAL` times that number:

```
SELECT DATE '1998-08-31' 
 +  CAST((SELECT config.ask_gift_dt_diff 
          FROM ddcoe_tbls.gift_lnk_config config
          WHERE bzd_cnst_lnk_ctg_cd = 'ASK GIFT DATE RANGE') AS INTERVAL DAY)

SELECT DATE '1998-08-31' 
 + (SELECT config.ask_gift_dt_diff * INTERVAL '1' DAY
    FROM ddcoe_tbls.gift_lnk_config config
    WHERE bzd_cnst_lnk_ctg_cd = 'ASK GIFT DATE RANGE')
```

Comment: You are just too good Sir :) Thanks again for saving my life .